# HTML Bootstrap Modal not appear in variable javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add the HTML script in Javascript variable as shown below. Everything is fine for the others line. However, for the modal box. After I click the button, the modal box not appears. Anytone can fix this?

```
<script>
            var longStr = 
            '<div class="className">\
                <b>Captured Info by <span style="color:blue">{{ user }}</span></b><br><br>\
                <b>Altitude : </b>{{ altitude }} meter<br>\
                <b>LonLat : </b>{{ longitude }}&#176 , {{ latitude }}&#176<br>\
                <b>Date Taken : </b>{{ date_taken }} <br><br>\
                <b>Image</b> <br>\
                <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ image }}" ismap />\
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal</button>\
                    #error here -> <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">\
                            <div class="modal-dialog">\
                                    <div class="modal-content">\
                                            <div class="modal-header">\
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>\
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>\
                                                </div>\
                                                <div class="modal-body">\
                                                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>\
                                                </div>\
                                                <div class="modal-footer">\
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>\
                                                </div>\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>'

            ;
```

Below is the CSS, script

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```
<!--     Fonts and icons     -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<!-- CSS Files -->
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='assets/css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css')}}" +"?v=2.0.1"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='assets/css/demo.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-PmY9l28YgO4JwMKbTvgaS7XNZJ30MK9FAZjjzXtlqyZCqBY6X6bXIkM++IkyinN+" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--   Core JS Files   -->
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='assets/js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-jzngWsPS6op3fgRCDTESqrEJwRKck+CILhJVO5VvaAZCq8JYf8HsR/HPpBOOPZfR" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-vhJnz1OVIdLktyixHY4Uk3OHEwdQqPppqYR8+5mjsauETgLOcEynD9oPHhhz18Nw"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you load the jquery, bootstrap.js and popper.js correctly?

Comment: @BearNithi hi, yes. already edit the post.

Comment: where do you render `longStr` in HTML?

Comment: `var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(captured[object].lng,captured[object].lat).transform(epsg4326, projectTo),{ description: longStr },{ externalGraphic: "{{url_for('static', filename='marker.png')}}", graphicHeight: 30, graphicWidth: 30, graphicXOffset: -12, graphicYOffset: -25 });`

here. actually, this is open layer for mapping @BearNithi